# Application not present in developer list and in search

Tags: android, google-play

last weekend I released a new application but it is not yet present in the search result nor in the developer list.

If I access it via direct package url it works fine

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.luxteam.sacal

but if I click on the developer name, leading to

https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Massimiliano+Cannarozzo

it's not present.

Do you have any idea?

EDIT:
Application now present in both search and developer page.

Comment: Can you see this app in your dev console?

Answer (score 1):

I think Google is having some indexing problem. A lot people is with the same problem right now, for example me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775868/android-app-not-showing-under-my-developer-account-id-in-google-play-store/19776088#19776088 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770827/i-cant-see-my-developer-page-in-google-play

Comment: Do you have any more official reference? e.g. a support ticket